# Convert callback function to generator

Tags: python

Suppose I am building a library function that does work incrementally and passes the results through callback functions:

```
def do_something(even_callback, odd_callback):
    for i in range(10):
        if i % 2:
            even_callback(i)
        else:
            odd_callback(i)
```

Some callers care about handling the two types of events differently, and so they use separate callback implementations. However many callers don't care about the difference and just use the same implementation:

```
do_something(print, print)
```

For these callers, it would be more convenient to have a version of the function `do_something_generator`:

```
for result in do_something_generator():
    print(result)
```

Leaving aside the solution of rewriting `do_something` to be a generator itself, or async/thread/process, how could I wrap `do_something` to turn it into a generator? (Also excluding "get all the results in a list and then yield them")

---

Per discussion in the comments, one possible solution would be to rewrite the do_something function to be a generator and then wrap it to get the callback version, however this would require tagging the events as "even" or "odd" so they could be distinguished in the callback implementation.

In my particular case, this is infeasible due to frequent events with chunks of data - adding tagging into the base implementation is a nontrivial overhead cost versus callbacks.

Comment: "Also excluding "get all the results in a list and then yield them" that is really all you could do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my point in excluding that is doing so would be a major disadvantage versus the existing callback method. The callback method will allow for reacting to each incremental result as it becomes ready

Comment: _e.g. not my code, can't modify_ - what about patching the function during runtime?

Comment: @ChristianKarcher that's a fair framing challenge. To be honest, it IS my own code, but I'd rather only have to write the full implementation once and then provide multiple "adapters" for the various ways of calling it, including a yield-based adapter.  The REAL function takes two callbacks (for different kinds of events), but often callers will pass the same function for both, and in that case a yield-based method would be more convenient than forcing the caller to create a callback function.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher so the yield form of the call would actually lose resolution (e.g. without some extra label, it wouldn't be clear which type of event was being yielded). I was hoping that the callback form of the function would be general enough to support a yield-based wrapper of some kind that has the same "run some code as each event occurs" efficiency. However I'm starting to think my question is equivalent to "how can I save off a stack frame and then return to it later"

Comment: it would be easier to start with the "most granular" one, i.e. the _yield_ version, and then implement wrappers for _bulk_ results. Would this approach be an option?

Comment: @ChristianKarcher sadly the yield version is _less_ granular. The callback version accepts two callbacks for two different streams of data, and chunks are passed to the callbacks as they occur. In many cases, a caller will choose to use the same callback function for both streams of data, so a yield version might be more intuitive for them. I could make the "real" implementation yield-based, but then I have to include a tag with each chunk to describe which stream its for, and depending on chunk size, tagging could be nontrivial extra bytes (of the total).

Comment: @ChristianKarcher let me update the question to be more accurate to that use-case - I was trying to make it an MVP example rather than include too much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Leaving aside the solution of rewriting do_something to be a generator itself, or async/thread/process, how could I wrap do_something to turn it into a generator?

Assuming that you exclude rewriting the function on the fly so that it actually yields rather than calls callbacks, this is impossible.

Python is single-threaded.  What you're describing has two functions running at once, one of which (the wrapped) signals to the other (the wrapper) whenever a value is ready and then passes that value up, whereupon the wrapper yields it.  This is impossible, unless one of the following conditions is met:

- the wrapped function is in a separate thread/process, able to run by itself
- the wrapped function switches execution whilst passing a value rather than calling callbacks

Since the only two ways of switching execution whilst passing a value are yielding or async yielding, there is no way of doing this in the language if your constraints are met.  (There is no way to write a callback which signals to the wrapper to yield a value and then allows the wrapped function to resume, except by placing them in different threads.)

What you're describing sounds kind of like protothreads, only for python, by the way.

However there's no reason not to write it the other way round:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Monad = namedtuple("Monad", "is_left,val")

def do_stuff():
    for i in range(10):
        yield Monad(is_left=bool(i%2), i)

def do_stuff_always():
    for monad in do_stuff():
        yield monad.val

def do_stuff_callback(left_callback, right_callback):
    for monad in do_stuff():
        if monad.is_left:
            left_callback(val)
        else:
            right_callback(val)
```

I can't resist calling these structures monads, but perhaps that's not what you're trying to encode here.

Comment: I think without some really ugly implementation-specific stack manipulation, this is the right approach. Thanks!